# Save images from API in gallery in Flutter

Tags: flutter, api

Can anyone please tell me that how can I save images in the gallery for an offline purpose from the API in flutter? I use [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) and [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for that but can't get success.

Answer (score 0):

By using the same package `flutter_downloader`:

```
await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [image_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader) package. But don't forget read/write permissions for devices. You can check the packages readme file.

```
 await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url,
                                 destination: AndroidDestinationType.custom('sample')
                                 ..inExternalFilesDir()
                                 ..subDirectory("custom/sample.gif"),
     );
```